# Not recognising Color from different class

Tags: java, colors, jpanel

So I want to set my Rectangle's color to whatever the `JColorChooser` picks, but unfortunately, I don't think that it recognises it as it just stays black, unless I assign it a real color like `Color.BLUE`.

This is the rectangle which should get the color from the other class:

```
TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(500,300,250,400);
        g.setColor(jpp.bodyColour);
        g.fillRect((int)r.getX(),(int)r.getY(),(int)r.getHeight(),(int)r.getWidth());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("banana", 50, 60);

    }
```

and this is the class which has the color itself

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProjectJPanel extends JFrame {

    public JButton b;
    public JButton u;
    public JButton l;
    public JButton r;

    public String s;

    public Color color = (Color.WHITE);
    public JPanel panel;
    public Color bodyColour;
    public Color doorColour;
    public Color wheelColour;

    public TestProjectJPanel(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

        // bodyColour button
        b = new JButton("Body Colour");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                bodyColour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick the colour", bodyColour);
                if (bodyColour == null) 
                    bodyColour = Color.RED;

            }
        });

        u = new JButton("Wheel Colour");
        u.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                wheelColour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick the colour", wheelColour);
                if (wheelColour == null) 
                    wheelColour = (Color.BLACK);

            }
        });

        l = new JButton("Door Colour");
        l.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                doorColour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick the colour", doorColour);
                if(doorColour==null) 
                    doorColour = (Color.RED);

            }
        });

        r = new JButton("Change Name");
        r.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What name do you want to change it to?");

            }
        });

    }


}
```

This is the whole code, which the `Rectangle` is included in.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProjectDialog extends JPanel {

    TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(500, 300, 250, 400);

        g.setColor(jpp.bodyColour);

        g.fillRect((int) r.getX(), (int) r.getY(), (int) r.getHeight(), (int) r.getWidth());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        g.drawString("banana", 50, 60);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();

    /* JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just about to draw a REALLY GOOD 2D car \n just need input please.");

    jpp.s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
    if(jpp.s == null || (jpp.s != null && ("".equals(jpp.s))))   
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input/pressed cancel, closing program.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + jpp.s); */

    JFrame f = new JFrame("My 2D Car Drawing");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jpp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setSize(1440,900);
    f.add(new TestProjectDialog(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(jpp.b, SpringLayout.SOUTH);  // bodyColour
   // f.add(jpp.u, SpringLayout. NORTH); // wheelColour
   // f.add(jpp.l, SpringLayout.WEST); // doorColour
  //  f.add(jpp.r, SpringLayout.EAST);  // changeName

    f.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Could anyone help me and give me a solution for why it's not recognising the color?

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner

Comment: Maybe you need to call `repaint()` after picking the colour.

Comment: @khelwood doesn't work :(

Comment: As I said yesturday, you need to pass the color from the `TestProjectJPanel` to the component responsible for painting it then call `repaint` on the component to inform the repaint manager that the component needs to be repainted

Comment: Woops, sorry. I'll edit it in. It's the TestProjectJPanel object

Comment: @madProgrammer Also, sorry for asking a relatively simple question, but how would I do that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Haven't I already passed it using the g.setColor(jpp.bodyColour); ? I've put repaint(); literally everywhere where the JColorChooser is but it's not working :/

Comment: Without seeing a runnable example, I have no idea what `jjp` actally us

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I've formatted your code for you. Please __format__, and __comment through__ your code yourself next time - The formatter that comes with your IDE is helpful and it improves the readability of these questions. Also, that's a lot of code. Please see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem, it is impossible to 100% sure, but from the sounds of it, you have created two more instances of `TestProjectJPanel` and/or paint panel, so what you think you're drawing to isn't actually on the screen.

However, it also sounds like you're not adhering to basic OO design, ensuring that the object is self managed, but instead, allowing the object to ascertain it's state from the properties of another object.

Instead, your paint/rectangle pane should be self contained, that is, all the properties it needs should be managed by it (this could also include a model, but that's going beyond the problem at hand).

For example, the `ControlPane` manages the interactions between the user (choosing a color) and the setting of that color on the `PaintPane`, which deals only with painting the results...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorTest();
    }

    public ColorTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                PaintPane paintPane = new PaintPane();
                ControlPane controlPane = new ControlPane(paintPane);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(paintPane);
                frame.add(controlPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        public ControlPane(PaintPane paintPane) {
            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Color");
            add(colorButton);

            colorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(ControlPane.this, "Background", paintPane.getFillColor());
                    if (color != null)
                        paintPane.setFillColor(color);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private Color fillColor = Color.RED;

        public PaintPane() {}

        public Color getFillColor() {
            return fillColor;
        }

        public void setFillColor(Color fillColor) {
            this.fillColor = fillColor;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(fillColor);
            g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So I have to create setfillColor(Color fillColor) and then just add paintPane.setFillColor(color) into my program?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, the Color of the rectangle should be managed by the paint panel

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try it now, thankyou :) Anything else I shall add?